# Wordpress: Include new template for a page using query var with rewrite endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to load a new page template when a query var is appended at the end of my page url:
Original url: example.com/testpage/
with variable added to the end: example.com/testpage/amp

Then it would load up a custom php template. 
This seems like a straight forward operation, but I cannot get it to work. 
The url loads with the /amp variable at the end, but the template does not load.  If I remove the condition "get_query_var('amp')" then it loads up the template no problem.  What am I missing?   Thanks :)

Here is my working code:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'register_query_var' ); 
function register_query_var( $vars ) {
$vars[] = 'amp';
    return $vars;
}
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'amp', EP_PAGES );

add_filter( 'template_include', 'use_amp_template', 99 );

function use_amp_template( $template ) {
global $wp_query;
 if ( get_query_var( 'amp' ) && is_page() ) {
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'amptemplate.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
    }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a good fix on my own.  Here is the code if it would help anyone. 
Adding 'amp' after a page or post will load up different templates for amp versions of the page.
example.com/samplepage/amp
or
example.com/samplepost/amp

```
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'register_query_var' ); 
    function register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'amp';
        return $vars;
}
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'amp', EP_PAGES | EP_PERMALINK );


add_filter( 'template_include', 'use_amp_template', 99 );

function use_amp_template( $template ) {
global $wp_query;

if(isset( $wp_query->query['amp'] ) && is_page()){

    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'amppagetemplate.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template;
    }
}

if(isset( $wp_query->query['amp'] ) && is_single()){

    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'ampposttemplate.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template;
    }
}

return $template;
}
```